# Remove Windows Defender in new Windows update 5/29/16

Tags: windows-10

The latest update has turned on Windows Defender and disabled my Avast Antivirus.
I HATE Windows Defender on many levels.  I've turned it off, but my Avast program still won't load and run.
I need Windows Defender and Microsoft's half brained new ideas out of my life. 
HELP!

Comment: If Avast won't run, you need to get an update from them.  Windows update apparently knows you will need an update before Avast will run, so it turned on Windows defender for you.  Not saying that's politically correct on Microsoft's part but seems that's what's happened.

Comment: Installing a new antivirus turns off Windows defender but the services run in background. May be reinstalling the antivirus works.

Comment: As @Biswa mentions, Defender runs, but only *if* SmartScreen is enabled. Try downloading and reinstalling Avast! Be sure you connect to the internet at least weekly to update the virus definitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to disable defender (personally I would advise against this), here are the steps to do so; you're removing it via group policy.

1. Open the run command (win+r)
2. Type gpedit.msc and hit enter to open local group policy editor
3. Go to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Defender
4. Under Windows Defender, there is an option, 'turn off windows defender'. Set this to enabled.
5. Click Apply, then hit OK.
6. Restart to get rid of the shield icon in the user tray.